# MySql - How to insert data from another table?

Tags: mysql

This is the scheme I am working on:

[image]
, I'm trying to insert data to `takes` table in the following condition:
if there's a student whose studied at 2015, semester=2, grade<80 then insert (on a new record) his student id, course id, year=2015, semester=3

I've tried several ways to do it but couldn't succeed

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: You can use `INSERT INTO.. SELECT`. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html Try something, and share the latest code attempt of yours to the question; so that we can put you in the right direction.

Comment: What you've tried so far? Please post code.

Comment: What value gets inserted for the grade?  Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  You should at least take 5 minutes to invest in your question, and add sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

is that you asking or what?